# Check all checkbox in table with pagination

Tags: javascript, laravel, checkbox, pagination

I'm looking for a solution to check all checkbox of a table with pagination. I'm using laravel pagination :

```
$webclients = WebClient::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(20);
```

But i encounter a problem :

The display page work good, but all the other rows on all other pages doesn't check. And if a i change the page, all checked checkboxes become uncheck.

I don't know if is exist a solution in javascript or in PHP with appends data ?

Can i get all the hidden node of a paginate table in Jquery or JS ?

Many thanks for the help !

Comment: Laravel Pagination uses `?page=X`, a Query String param, to navigate between pages, which is a separate request each time, and will not remember checkbox states (a front-end JS thing) between them. So no, there isn't really an easy way to do that with PHP/Laravel pagination (you _could_ use sessions, or something similar to remember the checked state, but it's messy). Did you try [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)? It's a JS (front-end) plugin that hides/shows pages, so checkbox state can be remembered.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, i try to do it without DataTables because i don't need any search or sort function. But if i've no choice i'll use it.